Can I use MISRA-2023 with C++14?
I would like to follow the MISRA C++:2023 coding guideline. But it targets C++17, while the code and compiler follow C++14.
The document reads:

The guidelines within this document target C++17, and they
may not be appropriate or adequate when applied to other versions of the language — specifically, additional guidelines may be needed to prevent undesirable behaviours that arenot covered by this document.

But I would see C++14 as a subset of C++17 (with only few breaking changes). Would I not be MISRA-C++-2023 compliant or only with additional rules?

Some big changes happened in C++17.  I would not expect you to be compliant using C++14.

Just give it a try. Most MISRA rules will be compliant with C++14. I doubt there is rule which enforces use of some C++17 features. It is more probable MISRA-2023 is able to read C++ code which uses C++17 features and has some rules of good practices for it.

@NathanOliver are you implying that there are some MISRA-C++-2023 rules that mandate C++17 constructs? I can't think of anything where a correct C++14 program would be problematic when compiled under C++17

@Caleth A correct C++ program doesn't need to be MISRA compliant. MISRA is about using a restricted safe(r) subset of the language. I don't know which subset MISRA deems safe, but it may exclude some C++14 constructs that have a (safer, nicer, more expressive) C++17 equivalent.

@Caleth I'm more concerned of going the other way.  For instance C++17 introduced more sequencing guarantees for operators.  If MISRA says go ahead and use those as they are safe, and you use C++14 where they are not safe and unsequenced, then you can have issues.

@alter_igel you've got it the wrong way round. The examples you should be talking about is things C++17 removed, like std::auto_ptr

@Caleth If I were to write such guidelines, I would absolutely mandate at least [[fallthrough]].

The other alternative you have is finding a C++17 compiler. One would really hope that satisfying MISRA would imply the parts that are valid C++14 have the same behaviour under both standards.

@Caleth Sequencing rules for assignment, for stuff like i=i++; was muddy in C++11 and C++14. Essentially is was UB still just like in C. Then C++17 clarified this and that might matter for a lot of MISRA rules regarding ++, side effects and sequencing.

@Lundin I meant that a hypothetical "MISRA2023 for C++14" would have forbidden those constructs, so code that satisfied that would also satisfy MISRA2023 using a C++17 compiler

The MISRA C++:2023 document itself is non-public, so it's hard to give an authoritative answer. However, your question boils down to "Can I write C++14 code that conforms to MISRA C++:2023?" and the answer is "Of course you can."
Now, suppose MISRA C++:2023 had said "Rule 42.42: Every program must contain at least one fold-expression." Then you'd be out of luck, because there's no way to write a C++14 program that conforms to that rule. But I'm pretty sure that MISRA C++:2023 doesn't actually say any such thing. As @Lundin commented, MISRA is more interested in banning newfangled features than mandating them.
Second: As @NathanOliver commented, MISRA C++:2023 might say something like "Rule 42.43: Ensure that no object is modified twice in the same expression, unless it's on opposite sides of an assignment expression. For example (a++) + (a++) is forbidden, but (a++) = (a++) is permitted." You would have to be smart enough to realize that even though (a++) = (a++) was permitted by MISRA C++:2023, it was still forbidden (that is, UB) in C++14. (The behavior of that expression wasn't defined until C++17.) So this won't physically prevent you from writing good code in the intersection of C++14 and MISRA C++:2023... but it does mean that some parts of the document might be misleading, and you'd have to watch out for that.
However, that's par for the course in C++. Even if you were using the latest and greatest MISRA C++:2023 with C++23 or whatever, you could still easily write a program with bugs in it, either by not knowing the quirks of the language or simply by, you know, writing bugs. Following MISRA's rules cannot eliminate that chance. So, I don't think there's any qualitative difference between

writing code in the intersection of MISRA C++:2023 and well-defined C++17 and correct program behavior

writing code in the intersection of MISRA C++:2023 and well-defined C++14 and correct program behavior


The latter won't really be any harder than the former.

Finally, what about tooling? To assert you're staying within MISRA C++:2023, you need a compiler that diagnoses MISRA C++:2023 violations. Do you have one? Does that compiler support C++14? If it doesn't, then again you're completely out of luck. If it does, then I'm sure you're fine.


Blockquote: I would like to follow the MISRA C++:2023 coding guideline[s]. But it targets C++17, while the code and compiler follow C++14.

Do you want to run your diesel engine on petrol?

Blockquote: But I would see C++14 as a subset of C++17 (with only few breaking changes). Would I not be MISRA-C++-2023 compliant or only with additional rules?

Use Autosar C++ 14 Guidelines instead, which is a 70% reference to MISRA C++ 2008.
You will not be able to make C++14 compliant with Rule 4.1.1 without a Deviation. Further, read the MISRA Compliance:2020, which is mandated for use with MISRA C++ 2023.
